# fluent nhibernate on postgresql: define default column value to current UTC date?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, constraints

How does one do this?

I had assumed it was something like this:

```
Map(x => x.PersistedTimeStamp)
    .CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>()
    .Generated.Insert();
```

...this does nothing, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Generated.Insert()` only means "the DB will generate this value on insert; retrieve it for me afterwards"

Instead, just set the property to `DateTime.UtcNow` in the constructor.

Comment: There's no way to do that without modifying the POCO?  No interceptor or anything? My classes are autogenerated, that's going to be a pain.

Comment: Sure, you can implement `IPreInsertEventListener`, for example. Google that and you'll see some examples.

Comment: That seems to be implemented across an entire entity, or even the entire data model... it seems impractical to do that.  There's no way to configure a single property to a computed value upon insert?

Comment: Uh? You asked for an interceptor; event listeners are pretty similar. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Sigh, I guess I don't know what I'm looking for.  I just wanted a way to fluently configure a property mapping so that it defaulted to a current UTC timestamp.